# Cognitive services - Face Identify - Error recognitionModel' is incompatible

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition

I am checking Cognitive Services Face API with Postman.

I am able to `create person group`, `add person to group` , `add face` , `train` but when I `identify` with another image, it says -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "'recognitionModel' is incompatible."
    }
}
```

Screenshot of Postman:

[image]

[image]

**Please note:**

1. When I created the group, I mentioned `"recognitionModel": "recognition_02"`
2. When detecting image, I mentioned `"recognitionModel": "recognition_02"`

Still getting error on identification.

Comment: Please show us the result of the GET operation on your personGroup with id 1 (https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395246) and also the content of your Detect request.

Comment: yes, passing recognition model in the api worked for me, thanks a lot for your help. If you can post this as an answer, i can accept it

Comment: I don't understand: you mean that you had the problem despite having set the recognitionModel correctly, but finally you did not pass those values in reality?

Comment: i was passing the value in body , and not in URL while detecting

Comment: It should be in the JSON body, it's not in the query. Maybe you should add details of your calls so that your question might help other people. In other case, it's misleading

Answer (score 0):

During the Face Detect call, the recognistionModel needs to be in the Url matching with the model what has been used during FaceList creation as followed.

`https://{endpoint}/face/v1.0/detect?**recognitionModel=recognition_03**`

Now use the returned faceId from the above call in Face FindSimilars call body.